# Change all dates of all files in directory

Tags: command-line, date

I have a directory with the following files:

```
$ ls -l  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4129128 Aug  7  2013 A-32.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4106876 Aug  7  2013 A-37.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4192644 Aug  7  2013 A-38.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4324212 Aug  7  2013 A-42.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4147792 Aug  7  2013 A-44.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4271768 Aug  7  2013 A-53.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4330804 Aug  7  2013 A-86.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4299692 Aug  7  2013 A-87.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4135748 Aug  7  2013 A-91.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4240316 Aug  7  2013 A-92.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4325900 Aug  7  2013 A-93.JPG
```

I want to change Aug 7 2013 to today. I tried this but it has no effect:

```
$ touch -a --no-create *
```

What is the correct command?

---

In response to @steeldriver:

```
$ touch -a --no-create *  
$ ls -lu  
total 45436  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4129128 Apr 14 09:25 A-32.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4106876 Apr 14 09:25 A-37.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4192644 Apr 14 09:25 A-38.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4324212 Apr 14 09:25 A-42.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4147792 Apr 14 09:25 A-44.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4271768 Apr 14 09:25 A-53.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4330804 Apr 14 09:25 A-86.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4299692 Apr 14 09:25 A-87.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4135748 Apr 14 09:25 A-91.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4240316 Apr 14 09:25 A-92.JPG  
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername 4325900 Apr 14 09:25 A-93.JPG
```

So I guess I'm not sure which date I want to change. Maybe all dates associated with the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `-a`:

> `-a`     change only the access time

But `ls -l` shows the modification time, run `stat %y file` or `ls -lu` to see the updated Access time.

If you want to change modification and access time, leave out the `-a`:

```
touch --no-create *
```

or if you want to update modification time only, use `-m`.